# Are There Infinite Isomorphisms?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Is this true:

> If $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic spaces, where $\dim(V)>0$ and $\dim(W)>0$, then there are infinite isomorphisms $L\colon V \to W$.

Comment: The definitions says "there exist isomorphisms": this doesn't mean there are infinitely many, it also doesn't mean there aren't.  So at this stage the answer could be "yes", or "no", or "sometimes".  You will need to decide: given one isomorphism, can you find others?  Infinitely many others?

Comment: If $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic as vector spaces, then $\dim V = \dim W$ for whatever is the field of scalars common to both.  However some fields are finite, which might limit the number of isomorphisms.

Answer (score 4):

Three things:

- If $\dim V < \infty$ and the field is finite, we have that $V$ and $W$ are finite sets, hence admit only finitely many arbitrary maps between them.
- If the field is infinite, multiplication by all elements of $K \setminus \{0\}$ gives rise to infinitely many isomorphisms, once you have one given isomorphism.
- If the dimension of $V$ is infinite - say $X$ is a basis - we have $\operatorname{Sym}(X) \subset \operatorname{Aut}_K(V)$. The fact $|\operatorname{Sym}(X)|=\infty$ gives rise to infinitely many isomorphisms, once you have one given isomorphism. The size of the field does not matter for that argument.